# Which Aghori practices are different from Kapalika (Skull-Bearer) practices?

Tags: shiva, rituals, shaivism, shakti, shaktism

The legendary Kapalika sadhus, mentioned in Shaiva scriptures (including Puranas) were known for their rituals which took place with skulls and bones involved. Human dead body meat, blood, sacrifice and sadhnas of spirits/supernatural forces in the cremation grounds were common.

These are all the same things done by the Aghoris. So do Aghoris do anything different? Please tell about sadhna, mantras, kriyas etc.

[image]